# webpack split single package and its dependencies out of vendor

Tags: webpack, swagger-ui

I have a project where we use webpack 3. It's set up to split all node_modules into a vendor bundle.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: ({ resource }) => /node_modules/.test(resource)
}),
```

Recently, we started using swagger-ui on a particular page. Since the rest of the site doesn't use it, I'd like swagger-ui (and its dependencies) in its own, separate, vendor bundle.

The closest I can get is:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'swagger-ui',
    minChunks: ({ context }) => /swagger-ui/.test(context)
}),
```

It creates the second vendor bundle, but it only has the main swagger-ui package. That package uses a ton of other libraries like react and immutable.js (which the rest of the site does not use).

How can I get the dependencies out of the first bundle and into the swagger-ui bundle?

Comment: Why not lazy load it using `import()` in the code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with webpack - does `name: 'swagger-ui'` refer to an npm package? If so, Swagger UI provides a dependency free package named [`swagger-ui-dist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist) - will this suit your needs?